# Avoid php page call with post parameters from browser

Tags: php, ios, post

this is my first post, i'd like to ask you how can i avoid  a direct call of a php page passing POST parameters in the browser?Because I have an iOS application and this should send data to a php page with POST method and then the php page will store data on a database but i don't want that someone, which somehow find the page address, type directly in the browser the address of php page followed by post parameters. I've searched and find that creating a .htaccess file could prevent the php call but, being a newbie, i would like to ask if this prevent the direct passage of parameters on browser. 
Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: simply pass a secret key with your param when that key exists and valid do your stuff else redirect to some other page

Comment: is the PHP page being accessed via AJAX in your iOS application?

Comment: @BhavikShah no it isn't accessed via ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO.

You can't control the user-side operations. anybody that can call your php page - can send any parameter as he like to.

What you can do is this:

1) block all IP addresses without your own (if your IP is static).

2) add a secret parameter to all of your requests. and in php file add condition like

```
if($_POST["secret"]!="some secret string")
exit("No permissions");
```

Make the parameter name (or value...) - hard to guessing!

Comment: how can you contradict to your own answer? Initially you have mentioned BIG NO and then you yourself stated a way. hahhahahha....

Comment: and about .htaccess file? searching i've found that with such file i can block php page call, why in this case doesn't it work?because if someone  maybe sniff the parameters could see the secret key.

Comment: @BhavikShah The question is "Avoid php page call with post parameters from browser". so the short answer is NO.

Comment: @gcc - you right of course! in .htaccess you can block all of request (and your iOS app too) or block with password (your iOS app will fail to connect too) or block whitelist of IP (if your iOS have a static address). i wrote only the appropriate options.

Comment: but if a i create an .htaccess file will the request from my app be rejected as direct request from browser? it will be useless for my app. It's ok to use a secret password but i'm non protected against sniffing.

Comment: 1) in .htaccess you can set a specific IP to be permitted. 2) you can use secure http (https) against sniffing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to pass a secret code, work on https website and make some coditions for the variables that passed to your ftp like it must not be Null , if you are passing an email for example  you have to validate it's format... so you make it hard for the hacker to  get control :)